# Youtube API Player throws 403 (ok) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a video service powered by YouTube API, but i encounter a problem: when video start playing browser throws an error to browser console:

```
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?sdkv=h.3.0.0&url=example.com 403 (OK).
```

But when i test the same from localhost i can see ads on videos.

Comment: Are you running an AdBlock extension?

Comment: No, i do not use AdBlock extension

Answer (score 0):

**Basically, you're not allowed to place Google Ads in or around copyrighted material embedded in iFrames.**

The YouTube API requires you to use an `iframe` to embed the YouTube video player. If you look at the [Google Ads copyrighted material policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348688?ctx=as2&hl=en&rd=1#Copyrighted_material), you will find the following statement.

> When a website displays someone else's website within a frame or window on their own site, this is considered framing content. Placing Google ads on such pages is strictly prohibited.

[This video from the same page](https://youtu.be/3ocGFz6uExM) explains what they mean by "framing". They also simplify the whole message by saying:

> If the content isn't yours or you don't have permission to use it, you can't monetize it with Google Ads.

**If you want to advertise through an embedded YouTube video [this page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en) explains how to legally do that.**